# Regular expression causes js hint error

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

Hi I am using this `RegExp` to parse a url.

```
var urlRegex = /^(?:(?:ht)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?:\w+:\w+@)?((?:(?:[-\w\d{1-3}]+\.)+(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|edu|co\.uk|ac\.uk|it|fr|tv|museum|asia|local|travel|[a-z]{2}))|((\b25[0-5]\b|\b[2][0-4][0-9]\b|\b[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]\b)(\.(\b25[0-5]\b|\b[2][0-4][0-9]\b|\b[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]\b)){3}))(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?:#(?:[-\w~!$ |\/.,*:;=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$/i;
```

The problem is it causes an error in js hint:

`message="Unescaped &apos;-&apos;."`

Is the a way around this?

Comment: You'd better to write how you want to parse `URL` with desire result !

Comment: the regex is working fine according to me

Comment: To clarify the regex is fine, that it's causing a jslint error is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var urlRegex = /^(?:(?:ht)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?:\w+:\w+@)?((?:(?:[\-\w\d{1-3}]+\.)+(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|edu|co\.uk|ac\.uk|it|fr|tv|museum|asia|local|travel|[a-z]{2}))|((\b25[0-5]\b|\b[2][0-4][0-9]\b|\b[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]\b)(\.(\b25[0-5]\b|\b[2][0-4][0-9]\b|\b[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]\b)){3}))(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[\-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?:(?:\?(?:[\-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[\-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[\-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[\-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?:#(?:[\-\w~!$ |\/.,*:;=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$/i;
```

(I've replaced all `[-\w\d...` with `[\-\w\d...`)